# Windows Store App: prevent duplicate code in two almost identical User Controls

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-store-apps

So I've got two User Controls in my Windws Store App, that look and work almost the same:

[Control 1 http://image-upload.de/image/FbKYsa/319b71644f.png](http://image-upload.de/image/FbKYsa/319b71644f.png)
[Control 2 http://image-upload.de/image/Hd9eMW/b78fca7c85.png](http://image-upload.de/image/Hd9eMW/b78fca7c85.png)

The events and event handling on the controls is identical, the only difference is that the second control has an additional ComboBox as you can see.
How can I prevent code duplication and doubled work whenever I change some functionality?

I tried to pack the identical controls into a resource dictionary but could not figure out how to access the control elements in the dictionary's code-behind.
As far as I know I also can't derive the second control, since the first uses XAML.

My last idea would be to use only one class and give a flag to the constructor to add a ComboBox if needed. But it just doesn't appear to be the right way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe throw them in a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227647) with a Visibility Converter on the additional Combo plugged into a public bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just done something similar on a app. My functionality required two text boxes for password entry and the OK, Cancel buttons to be available in both controls, however one of the controls also needed to display Radio Buttons for encoding types (these buttons were in a StackPanel). I added a parameter to the constructor as shown below:

```
    public PasswordInputBox(bool isForImage)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (isForImage)
            //initialize actions for that part of the EmbedTypePanel;
        else
            EmbedTypePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Then if you need the control with the extra combo box you can initialize it, else you just collapse it so the user is none the wiser.

Comment: I decided to go with this solution. It's the least code overhead.